# Enlarging and rescaling a picture down onclick in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-resizing

First time poster. I'm trying to get a simple, if possible, single function in HTML & JS to resize an image up and then scale it back down to its initial size between different pictures on a single page. So:

- If an image isn't enlarged, enlarge the clicked image.
- If an image is enlarged, if it's the same element that's being clicked, back to initial size
- If an image is enlarged that isn't the element being clicked, finding out which image is enlarged, scaling it down to initial size and scaling the clicked element up

There are 8 images in total. I created an array to change the value between 1 and 0 to perhaps use a count to find which number in the array wasn't 0 and then resize down but I don't know how to get that data or change the data to represent which image was clicked to enlarge to change that specific value in the array for example if [5] was clicked the value of [5] would become 1 and then a java function would cycle through and determine it's the 6th image and also enlarge it.

```js
var imgEnlarged = 0;
var otherEnlargedImgs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,];

function imgEnlarge(){ 
    if (imgEnlarged==0){          //Basic function if no enlarged, enlarge click element
        document.getElementById("0").style.width = "400px";
        document.get
        imgEnlarged = 1;
        otherEnlargedImgs[getElementById("0")] = 1 
    }
    else if (imgEnlarged==1) {    //If an image is enlarged, is it this one? If so, resize image
        document.getElementById("0").style.width = "300px";
        imgEnlarged = 0;
        otherEnlargedImgs[0] = 0
    }
    else if (imgEnlarged==1 && imgEnlargedOther==1)  { //if enlarged, which? Close other, open current element
        document.getElementById("0").style.width = "300px";
        imgEnlarged = 1
        otherEnlargedImgs[0] = 1
    }
}

function imgAssign() {

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grdsngrid">
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="0" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img0.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="1" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img1.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="2" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img2.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="3" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img3.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="4" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img4.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="5" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img5.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="6" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img6.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
      <div class=grdsnbox><img id="7" onclick="imgEnlarge()" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img7.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, this only works (and the code is a bit messy, sorry, I'm very new to coding) with the first image or whichever image is clicked if creating a different function for each image. Is there a way to do this that doesn't require each image to get its own function.

The imageAssign function was to assign the number to position in the array of the specific image clicked but again, this required using multiple functions.

var imgEnlarged is to check if an image has been enlarged, not specifically which image has been enlarged.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: You can have one function that checks which img is currently being processed based on the `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first we need to check that clicked image is enlarged or not while clicking on image. If clicked image is enlarged then its width should be set to 300px. After that we need loop through the images. Please see the code below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grdsngrid">
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_0" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img0.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_1" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img1.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_2" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img2.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_3" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img3.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_4" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img4.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_5" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img5.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_6" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img6.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
            <div class=grdsnbox><img id="img_7" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="content/img7.jpg"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            width:300px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function imgEnlarge(e){

            if(e.style.width=="300px" || e.style.width=="" ){
                e.style.width="400px";
            }
            else{
                e.style.width="300px";
            }

            var imgLength = document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;

            for(var i = 0; i<imgLength; i++){
                if(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].id==  e.id){
                    continue;
                }
                document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].style.width="300px";

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Notes: HTML id attribute value cannot be started with digits. Also notice I have set width of the images to 300px in the style tag.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! What is the (e) within the function for? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Please notice the 'this' keyword in ' imgEnlarge(this) '. It passes the clicked DOM element to 'e'. It refers to the clicked image.

Comment: Is there a way to get the img id via script too? Referring to the original code if I wanted to add another function onclick to retrieve the assigned img id, how would I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Definitely... You may get it by this code snippet :

document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].id

Here 'i' is for index number.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple functions. Just use JS [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword for each function call.

```js
var imgEnlarged = 0;
var otherEnlargedImgs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,];
function imgEnlarge(e){
  if (imgEnlarged==0){ //Basic function if no enlarged, enlarge click element
    e.style.width = "400px";
    imgEnlarged = 1;
    otherEnlargedImgs[e] = 1 
  }
  else if (imgEnlarged==1) { //If an image is enlarged, is it this one? If so, resize image
    e.style.width = "300px";
    imgEnlarged = 0;
    otherEnlargedImgs[0] = 0
  }
  else if (imgEnlarged==1 && imgEnlargedOther==1)  { //if enlarged, which? Close other, open current element
    e.style.width = "300px";
    imgEnlarged = 1
    otherEnlargedImgs[0] = 1
  }
}
function imgAssign() {

}
```

```css
.grdsngrid img{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="grdsngrid">
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="0" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="1" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="2" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="3" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="4" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="5" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="6" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
    <div class=grdsnbox><img id="7" onclick="imgEnlarge(this)" onclick="imgAssign()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"><figcaption></figcaption></div>
</div>
```